# Show all processes on a ComboBox

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, process

I want to make a `ComboBox` that shows all running processes.

Here the screenshot how it looks like. It's just emtpy.

[image: Screenshot of my application and combo box.]

XAML:

```
ComboBox Name="comboBox" RenderTransformOrigin="0.502,-0.751" Margin="129,112,111,217" SelectionChanged="comboBox_SelectionChanged"/>
```

C#:

```
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void  comboBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        comboBox.Items.Clear();
        Process[] MyProcess = Process.GetProcesses();
        for (int i = 1; i < MyProcess.Length; i++)
            comboBox.Items.Add(string.Format("{0} - {1}", MyProcess[i].ProcessName, MyProcess[i].Id));
    }
}
```

Comment: Setting the Items in a SelectionChanged event handler makes no sense. It will obviously not be called before there are any items in the ComboBox. Move that code to the MainWindow constructor.

Comment: SelectionChanged is triggered when you select an Item from the combobox. At the beginning your combobox is empty so this cannot be triggered.
I would suggest you get all Processes periodically, say every 5 Seconds and store them in a list or better observerble collection. That you can bind directly to the combox.

Comment: @Clemens If I but that in the MainWindow I`ll get this error: 'MainWindow' does not contain a definition for 'comboBox_SelectionChanged' and no accessible extension method 'comboBox_SelectionChanged' accepting a first argument of type 'MainWindow' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`SelectionChanged`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.selectionchanged?view=net-5.0) event does not work because it is only fired when the selection changes. You could use the [`DropDownOpened`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.combobox.dropdownopened?view=net-5.0) event instead.

```
ComboBox Name="comboBox" RenderTransformOrigin="0.502,-0.751" Margin="129,112,111,217" DropDownOpened="ComboBox_OnDropDownOpened"/>
```

Your event handler would look like this:

```
private void ComboBox_OnDropDownOpened(object? sender, EventArgs e)
{
   comboBox.Items.Clear();
   var processes = Process.GetProcesses();
   for (var i = 1; i < processes.Length; i++)
      comboBox.Items.Add($"{processes[i].ProcessName} - {processes[i].Id}");
}
```

An alternative is to expose a collection of processes that you initialize in the constructor and bind to the `ItemsSource` of the `ComboBox` in XAML. Then you can update the collection as needed, say periodically through a timer or via a command triggered by the user.

You could take one of these options for implementing the collection:

- Replace the whole collection, which requires implementing [`INotifyPropertyChanged`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged?view=net-5.0) and raising the [`PropertyChanged`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.propertychanged?view=net-5.0) event when you update the processes
- Use an [`ObservableCollection<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.objectmodel.observablecollection-1?view=net-5.0) to store processes and update it by modifying the collection, e.g. adding and removing processes or clearing it.